# Redirecting streams in bash shell - how to make unconditional on the rest of shell command line

Tags: debian, shell, io-redirection

I noted `apt` output is different when executed alone in Bash shell and when output is redirected to files.

For example:

```
$ apt install ./*.deb --simulate 1>111.txt 2>222.txt
```

adding redirection results in text `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.` in file for stream 2, whereas running apt w/out redirection does not display this text in shell window.

Why output depends on redirection? Maybe `apt` sees redirection as its` parameter? How can I write redirection to be unnoticed to other part of shell command line?

P.S. I saw it in Ubuntu 18 and `apt` is specific app, but maybe the issue is general to Unix, so I put only `shell` in tag.

Answer (score 2):

`apt` has been designed historically with interactive command-line use in mind, hence the coded warning, which has been done on purpose in/by `apt` and not by the shell.

However, `apt` is not necessarily parsing the command line; the shell has already done that job by the time it calls `apt`. What `apt` is doing is detecting that the `stdout` stream has been changed/redirected.

As for using `apt` in scripts, you have got the similar older command `apt-get` which does does more or less the same thing, and does not give that warning when `stdout` is redirected.

TLDR Is not the shell writing the error message in `stderr`, it is the `apt` command.

The fact that you are able to capture the `apt` `stderr` output in the shell is an artifact of Unix being a multitasking OS, and does not mean it is the shell producing that output.

PS. Doing an strace at the command, it can be seen `apt` writing that message:

```
strace apt get install bash > a
....
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "WARNING: ", 9WARNING: )                = 9
write(2, "apt", 3apt)                      = 3
write(2, " ", 1 )                        = 1
write(2, "does not have a stable CLI inter"..., 38does not have a stable CLI interface. ) = 38
write(2, "Use with caution in scripts.", 28Use with caution in scripts.) = 28
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
```

Comment: Is there any way to prevent e.g. apt from detecting redirection?

Comment: The canonical way is using the equivalent tools like `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. No switch/option to disable that behaviour that I know of.

Comment: What bothers me is not of cause that single additional phrase from apt, but the whole thing that when I see a long output in shell, I'd like to store it, do text search later, but cannot save it 100% the way it displays.

Comment: That is a whole different question actually. There is the `script` command for saving sessions of work.

Comment: `script` is what I can use, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

> "How can I write redirection to be unnoticed to other part of shell
>   command line?"

You don't have to do anything, the warning is on stdErr. Try this:

```
apt list adghdgd | grep .
2>/dev/null apt list adghdgd | grep .
```

If your distribution colors grep by default, you will see that the part that actually goes to grep gets colored.
In the second form stdErr gets suppressed alltoghether.

Grep also behaves differently, compare this:

```
echo hello | grep .
echo hello | grep . | cat
```

Second form is not colored, because grep notices its stdOut is not a terminal, but a pipe. How does he/she knows????

Compare

```
ls -l /proc/self/fd/1
( ls -l /proc/self/fd/1 ) | cat
```

In the first form stdOut is tty/pts. In the second, a pipe.